# Filling in the page with colour?

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

So I'm trying to fill in the header part above the border fully in colour. But there seems to be like 3px of white space that's just bordering the entire page. I made the margin and padding for the entire page 0 so I'm a little confused. Here's the page code:

```
<DOCTYPE html?>
<head>
<title> Brittany Corl - Web Developer</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSSCoding.css">
<div id="MainHeader"><img id="HeaderPhoto" src="HeaderPhoto.png" height="100 px" width="100 px">
<center><h1>Brittany Corl - Web Developer/Graphic Designer</h1></center></div>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="myskills.html">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

here's the CSS:

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 29px;
    border-bottom: medium solid black;
}

#HeaderPhoto {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

#MainHeader {
    background-color: #e0ffff;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #99C0F2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #5FA0F5;
}
```

Comment: For starters, your HTML is invalid. Try running it through http://validator.w3.org/ until you get rid of the errors. Then remember that the body element has a default margin, and the `<center>` element doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your css.

```
body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the margin and padding to zero for the body of the page.

```
body
{
 width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

or just add ,body after HTML